# Ruby on rails. Ransack search associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, ransack

I'm getting a little stuck with a ransack search form.

I need to search through a model's association, and bring results back when `name_cont` BUT ONLY WHEN AN associated model's `status == something`.

I have a `gig` model with a `has_many` `belongs_to` relationship with a `request` model and `user` model. The `request` model has attributes `status` and the `user` model has attributes `publicname`. I want to search `publicname_cont` and only show results from the requests that have a `status == "hired"`.

Currently my search brings back the results of `publicname` regardless or the `request` models `status`.

---

Gigs Controller:

```
@gigs = @q.result(distinct: false).notexpired.order(date: :asc).page(params[:page]).per(20)
```

Search form:

```
<%= search_form_for @q, url: welcome_index_url, remote: false do |f| %>

      <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], class: 'loc-search', placeholder: "Location"%>
      <%= f.search_field :locationname_cont, placeholder: "Bar name" %>
      <%= f.search_field :requests_user_publicname_cont, placeholder: "Band name" %>
      <%= f.submit %>
 <% end %>
```

Currently, I can search `requests_user_publicname_cont` and it gives me all the results as expected where the parameters match. 
I am looking for a way to search `requests_user_publicname_cont` AND `requests_status_eq, ("hired")`

---

I am not sure how to go about this, any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
@q = Gig.joins(:requests).where(requests: { status: 'hired' }).ransack(params[:q])
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you very much.